# Dynamic data matching between users based on user selection

Tags: php, sql

I'm hoping one of you more experienced programmers might be able to shed some light on this situation:

My site allows users to create a profile and enter in their favorite musicians, all of which reside in a pre-existing database of musicians.

Based on the artists they select, I want to display to them other users who have selected the same artists.

Can anyone offer suggestions on how this could be effectively accomplished?

I'm using SQL and PHP for the back end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a cross-reference table between users and musicians that defines the 'likes' relationship. At a minimum it would just need to contain the user id and musician id.

```
CREATE TABLE user_likes_musician (
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    musician_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, musician_id)
);
```

To find users who liked a particular musician you can just join the likes table with the users table:

```
SELECT * FROM users
    JOIN user_likes_musician
        ON (users.ID = user_likes_musician.user_id
            AND user_likes_musician.user_id <> [current user id]
            AND user_likes_musician.musician_id = [musicians id]);
```